# Types issue in Vue 3 Typescript based Project

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-props

I am using a v-for loop in Vue component, in which a Prop `options` which is `type of Object` should be iterated.

Props are declared in separate Files.

**Please see Below attachments:**

**Vue component :**

[image: Error on v-for loop]

Props are declared in, **props.ts :**

[image: Props declaration]

***Note: options returns an object of strings, which i am using for checkbox or radiobutton items.***

How to solve this type issue?

Comment: Have you tried to define your props as `Record<string, any>` instead of `Object`

Comment: I noticed you're using Vetur. Volar is the recommended extension for TypeScript support in Vue. Try switching.

Comment: I am using VsCodium, it has no Volar compatibility.

Comment: @Thomas yes i did, but it takes <String, Any> as a value and not as type and shows same as an error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using a default value which returns an object and by removing undefined type.

```
options: {
   type: Object,
   required: true,
   describe: "Provide a collection of components to render in the group",
   default: function (): unknown {
     return {}
   },
},
```

***Note: i am not sure if this is the proper solution for this Type problem.***